# Access an EnvironmentObject In a class that isn't a View

Tags: ios, swift, cocoa, swiftui, swift5

I am trying to access an EnviormentObject in a function to complete the Sign in with Apple signup and send the user info it receives to an EnviormentObject (Account) to access inside of a view. Here is what I have:

```
        if let authorizationCode = credentials.authorizationCode {
            let code = String(decoding: authorizationCode, as: UTF8.self)
            let parameters = ["code": code] as [String : Any]
            AF.request("http://192.168.86.243:3000/login/apple", method: .post, parameters: parameters, encoding: JSONEncoding.default).responseJSON { response in
                @EnvironmentObject var account: Account
                do {
                    let res = try JSON(data: response.data!)
                    print(res)
                    // Setting user object
                    account.user["id"] = res["user"]["id"].stringValue
                    account.user["email"] = res["user"]["email"].stringValue
                    account.user["name"] = res["user"]["name"].stringValue
                    account.token = res["token"].stringValue
                } catch {
                    account.error = true
                }
                
            }
        }
```

I am also open to any work arounds to access variables in a class inside of a view, etc.

Comment: As far as I know, that is not possible. Does your class Account has any relation to this class? You could make it a property inside Account to use its properties.

Comment: Where is this function? Can you create the environmental object in the scene delegate and then inject it into a class which includes this method?